# How to set big cookie header in karate

Tags: cookies, karate

As part of our automation we need to send very huge cookie header to the api.

cookie is as below
cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1041556506.1557744563; _gcl_au=1.1.139136457.1560512273; JabmoSP0id.ffef=d37c42bf-f223-43c6-a73c-fa502e23712d.1560512274.5.1561197329.1560589232.2561e1f4-79fe-4b63-88c6-157c6e8ed125; _gid=GA1.2.1289186220.1561356841; intercom-session-pk0ds0sg=TlZDS2xJQ3BjdldKQ3QzVkt2U1VkUUJ0WmhsVDBpaTY0YThBR0M0Y0dFMWs1azkwUlBlTWpUbWp1ZHN6MUtydS0tZm5CSlZYU0VPQnVJS1k1aFM2dkxkdz09--d615bb61f58bf243d7d949136c2d05d26aaac49a; route=lj-01; login=; lang=en; _ga=GA1.4.1041556506.1557744563; _gid=GA1.4.1289186220.1561356841; _pendo_accountId.029f7ddf-6593-4d82-5a65-a6c66fbf2b5c=AnupamaSoftwareAG; _pendo_visitorId.029f7ddf-6593-4d82-5a65-a6c66fbf2b5c=fldf7517754d071b07cb0e77; _pendo_meta.029f7ddf-6593-4d82-5a65-a6c66fbf2b5c=1358353967; userId=-2; JSESSIONID=CFDB00B95AF1C731356A04B01FF369E3; mp_62107c6714e5356c33d43ef8d8f43cee_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22fldf7517754d071b07cb0e77%22%2C%22%24device_id%22%3A%20%2216ab0cfc07a1b8-08fc4f883b46c5-454c062c-1fa400-16ab0cfc07b187%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24user_id%22%3A%20%22fldf7517754d071b07cb0e77%22%7D; intercom-session-no8pg948=emh3RjRGVzVmczQrTFdUaUZwWWliRTRBaDNlOEtmQ1VHcjh0NWl5eTZPNXVSdHdMU2VjMW9rRmt3WWZ0Q200Mi0tRitFT0Y1dkp6S2cvdkQ5OEFiR3N2Zz09--0f6b176d744b23f9b44bf693c5d9f429f84af84c; _gat_UA-60405455-1=1

If I separate the cookie (like if I send only jssionid it works)
but need to send full cookie

Need systax to send this cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically never need to set cookies because Karate will automatically send any cookies returned by the server in the next request. Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure - and you can set multiple cookies the "right way" in Karate like this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#cookie

What you have posted in your question seems to be the entire header made up of multiple cookies. It is most likely that you only need one or two of these for the server you are trying to test. I recommend you check with the team owning the service.

You can set the entire cookies header manually like this if you know what you are doing - but not recommended because of the above reason - and because you will need to handle / encode special characters etc - which is most likely why you ran into issues.

```
* header Cookie = '_ga=GA1.2.1041556506.1557744563; _gcl_au=1.1.139136457.1560512273; JabmoSP0id.ffef=d37c42bf-f223-43c6-a73c-fa502e23712d.1560512274.5.1561197329.1560589232.2561e1f4-79fe-4b63-88c6-157c6e8ed125; _gid=GA1.2.1289186220.1561356841;'
```

Note that the right-hand side above can be read from a text file like this:

```
* header Cookie = read('huge-string.txt')
```