# Response cookies using for next requests

Tags: cookies, karate

As I see from the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792335/how-to-set-big-cookie-header-in-karate?newreg=6627068162674e7f84aadca62533ddc2): Karate will automatically send any cookies returned by the server in the next request.

But when I send the request I see two sets of cookies in Set-Cookie of response: one is auto-created and another is real, that returned from the server.

When I printed `responseCookies`, I saw there only automatic cookies
and for the next request new cookies are generated and sent.

For my test I need to use cookies returned after the first request because it is a call to login service.

```
Feature: Using cookies in next request

    Background:
    Given url baseUrl
    And path LOGOUT_SERVICE_ENDPOINT
    And configure headers = read('classpath:headers.js')
    And def filename = 'classpath:resources/users/' + brand.toLowerCase() + '/user.json'
    And json user = read(filename)

    Scenario: Login
    When def login =  callonce read('classpath:features/login_service/login.feature') user
    * print login.responseCookies
    And request { arg1: '#(brand)'}
    And method post
    Then status 200
```

What is wrong in my feature or it is Karate issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> two sets of cookies in Set-Cookie of response:

Maybe that is a bug in the server ?

Also try using ["shared scope"](https://github.com/intuit/karate#shared-scope), because cookies also will be part of the "global" variables etc.

```
* callonce read('classpath:features/login_service/login.feature') user
* request { arg1: '#(brand)'}
```

If you are still stuck, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I found that a response from the server has one SET-COOKIE header (uppercased). It is not good but it is not the issue because according to HTTP header names are case-insensitive, according to RFC 2616:
4.2:

> Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names are case-insensitive. So I think that issue is in Set-Cookies header parsing"